# my query won't run, and I think the query is correct, anyone knows what I did wrong?

Tags: google-bigquery, group-concat

```
SELECT
  usertype CONCAT(start_station_name ,"to", end_station_name) AS route, 
  COUNT (*) AS num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64/60),2) AS duration
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
GROUP BY start_station, end_station, usertype
ORDER BY num_trips DESC LIMIT 10
```

This part of the query was underlined as a SYNTAX error on the big query (start_station_name,) I copied it the exact way my instructor did on a course. But it didn't return a result.

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, please accept it as a solution and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

fixed the query for you:

```
SELECT usertype, CONCAT(start_station_name ,"to", end_station_name) AS route, COUNT (*) AS num_trips, ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips GROUP BY start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype ORDER BY num_trips DESC LIMIT 10
```

there was a missing comma after usertype. there was missing parenthesis after int64. the group by had the wrong column names.

query runs and produces results.

Comment: then please accept my answer to mark your question as solved.